# WebView doesn't load iFrame video due to security policy violation

Tags: android, iframe, android-webview, android-chrome

I am trying to load an iFrame in my WebView.
The video/iFrame doesn't load reliably

**This is what happens :**

When I load the screen, in the webview's place there is blank space, but eventually the video might load, but most times, it doesn't load.
However, if I lock the screen and unlock it, the video loads just fine.

I extended the ChromiumWebClient and logged the following methods :

```
onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {}
onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {}
```

Turns out the video downloads 80% then, incurs the security exception, but it does seem to continue downloading in a short while and downloads 100%.

Despite downloading 100%, the webview doesn't show the video(player).

However, as mentioned above, if I lock and unlock the screen, (the now downloaded) video shows up correctly.

**iFrame**(could be from any source, not just vimeo) **:**

> "https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fplayer.vimeo.com%2Fvideo%2F215269493&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F215269493&image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F632188996_1280.jpg&key=0a5d85b22c79478aa887a7e8061bef56&type=text%2Fhtml&schema=vimeo' width='525' height='295' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>"

**Web view code :**

```
fun onResume() {
    videoWebView.onResume()
}

fun onPause() {
    videoWebView.onPause()
}


private fun loadVideo(videoWebView: WebView, iFrame: String) {
    videoWebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
    videoWebView.setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient())
    videoWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    videoWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    videoWebView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
    videoWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    videoWebView.loadData(
            iFrame,
            WebFormatUtil.MIMETYPE_HTML,
            WebFormatUtil.ENCODING_UTF8)      
}
```

I do have hardwareAcceleration and internet permission enabled in manifest

**The Logs throw the following (2 messages):**

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "The deviceorientation event is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://[shortened url](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for more details.", source: https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.69.8/js/player.js (11)
>
> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/-1316638038331145773' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: https://i.vimeocdn.com https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com https://f.vimeocdn.com https://vimeo.com https://secure.gravatar.com https://i0.wp.com https://i1.wp.com https://i2.wp.com https://player.vimeo.com https://*.ci.vimeows.com https://f.vimeocdn.com".
>                                                                          ", source: https://player.vimeo.com/video/215269493 (0)

This turns out to be a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807304) in the Chromium client and has not ben fixed yet.

**What I am looking for :**
I am looking for a way such that when I open the screen the video is shown, without having to turn on and off the screen.
Not sure if anything other than a hack around is possible.

Note : I have tried a lot of other answers, most of the deal with other issues such as config and so on.
I have isolated out the issue to be in ChromiumClient used for Android WebView, which those other answers are not about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed my issue :

```
private fun loadVideo(videoWebView: WebView, iFrame: String) {
    webView.setWebChromeClient(object: WebChromeClient() {
                override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage): Boolean {
                    if (consoleMessage.messageLevel() == ConsoleMessage.MessageLevel.ERROR) {
                        webView.onResume()
                    }
                    return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage)
                }
            })
      //......rest of the method like before
    }
```

Every time after lock/unlocking the screen, the video showed up fine.
What that means is that the `onPause()` and `onResume()` were  fired inside the webView.

Additionally, Every time the security exception is incurred the `onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage)` in Chromium client is fired with the tag ERROR.

This is a hack around, which so far has been safe, from my testing.
Until the actual issue is fixed, this works for me.